# change the background color of a certain part of the screen relative to some element in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `ImageView` and a `TextView` and I want to change the color of the background from the bottom to half the height of my `ImageView`. I tried to do that with a `View` like this:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/cyan"
        android:id="@+id/blue_background" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/credits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/credits"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/credits"
        android:layout_below="@id/resume_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
        TextView credits = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.credits);
        View background_blue = (View) findViewById(R.id.blue_background);
        background_blue.getLayoutParams().height = credits.getLayoutParams().height + (logo.getLayoutParams().height / 2);
    }
```

but it doesn't work, I get the entire background as blue instead of just the part I am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ViewTreeObserver**

```
final ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
ViewTreeObserver vto = logo.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
@Override 
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    logo.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); 
    int width  = logo.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = logo.getMeasuredHeight(); 

    background_blue.getLayoutParams().height = credits.getLayoutParams().height + (height / 2);

    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this workaround

Replace this

```
 <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/cyan"
        android:id="@+id/blue_background" />
```

With this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/blue_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/cyan" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and remove this line from Main Activity

```
background_blue.getLayoutParams().height = credits.getLayoutParams().height + (logo.getLayoutParams().height / 2);
```

Comment: I get the same.. the entire background blue

Comment: it seems to work but in my actual code I have more elements and if I introduce a LinearLayout I have to change more stuff in my xml